# Is there a way to do online A/B testing to see whether a google ad would be clicked on more?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I have some trafficked pages, but my ads are small and in places where they do not ruin the user experience. So they get a low click-through rate.

I am wondering if there is a way to test out ways to place them in different spots. Any way to test that out?

I am aware of the heat maps by the way, so I need something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Simply create different ad units in Adsense and use PHP or whatever you're using to get random numbers to alternate which Adsense code is printed. (Google "[rotate ads](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=rotate%20ads)" for various advice, scripts, plug-ins, etc) Then after awhile you can compare their results in the Performance Report of Adsense.

Of course this is easiest to do by placing two different ads in the same place and seeing which one has a higher CTR, but you can also test two different layouts this way by figuring out what elements you are changing and then printing or not printing the appropriate code based on the variable you are using to rotate the ads.

Answer (score 0):

I created multiple Ad units of the three most popular sizes (recommended by Google) and then worked out my design for where placement could alternate.  Skinny tower vs wide tower, small vs large banner, small vs large box.

Like Joshua recommends I ran these with rotate, each add would toggle it's choice in the desired location.  For each test iteration I waited 30 days to see the results.  If you make a new Ad Unit for each test you want to conduct it will be very easy to compare the results.

At the end of a few months the site in questions now has two ads locations, with a fixed size.